microk8s kubelet constantly restarting
OS: Ubuntu Desktop 24 LTS
Microk8s: v1.30.1 revision 6876
I was trying to bring up some containers, using helm, but the pods never get created:
sudo microk8s kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE            NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
container-registry   pod/registry-6c9fcc695f-8c5dk                1/1     Running   0          4d21h
kube-system          pod/calico-kube-controllers-77bd7c5b-7nw2b   1/1     Running   0          4d21h
kube-system          pod/coredns-864597b5fd-ch7g6                 1/1     Running   0          4d21h
kube-system          pod/hostpath-provisioner-7df77bc496-mbsbc    1/1     Running   0          4d21h

NAMESPACE            NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
container-registry   service/registry                 NodePort    10.152.183.90    <none>        5000:32000/TCP           4d21h
default              service/our-manager-postgres   NodePort    10.152.183.82    <none>        5432:30400/TCP           4d21h
default              service/our-manager-service    ClusterIP   10.152.183.164   <none>        80/TCP                   4d21h
default              service/kubernetes               ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP                  4d21h
kube-system          service/kube-dns                 ClusterIP   10.152.183.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   4d21h

NAMESPACE     NAME                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-node   1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   4d21h

NAMESPACE            NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
container-registry   deployment.apps/registry                  1/1     1            1           4d21h
default              deployment.apps/our-manager-postgres    0/1     0            0           4d21h
default              deployment.apps/our-manager-service     0/1     0            0           4d21h
kube-system          deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           4d21h
kube-system          deployment.apps/coredns                   1/1     1            1           4d21h
kube-system          deployment.apps/hostpath-provisioner      1/1     1            1           4d21h

NAMESPACE            NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
container-registry   replicaset.apps/registry-6c9fcc695f                1         1         1       4d21h
kube-system          replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-77bd7c5b   1         1         1       4d21h
kube-system          replicaset.apps/coredns-864597b5fd                 1         1         1       4d21h
kube-system          replicaset.apps/hostpath-provisioner-7df77bc496    1         1         1       4d21h

No errors, nothing..
When I check the logs of snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service, I see:
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: I0625 11:30:38.065063 3226369 daemon.go:44] Starting Proxy
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: I0625 11:30:38.065821 3226369 server_linux.go:69] "Using iptables proxy"
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: I0625 11:30:38.066942 3226369 server.go:1146] "Use of insecure cipher detected." cipher="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: I0625 11:30:38.067012 3226369 server.go:1146] "Use of insecure cipher detected." cipher="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: I0625 11:30:38.079408 3226369 server.go:1062] "Successfully retrieved node IP(s)" IPs=["192.168.225.128"]
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: I0625 11:30:38.079971 3226369 server.go:487] "Kubelet version" kubeletVersion="v1.30.1"
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: I0625 11:30:38.080019 3226369 server.go:489] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: I0625 11:30:38.080968 3226369 util_unix.go:103] "Using this endpoint is deprecated, please consider using full URL format" endpoint="/var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd.sock" URL="unix:///var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd.sock"
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: I0625 11:30:38.081110 3226369 dynamic_cafile_content.go:157] "Starting controller" name="client-ca-bundle::/var/snap/microk8s/6876/certs/ca.crt"
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: Error: failed to run Kubelet: validate service connection: validate CRI v1 runtime API for endpoint "/var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd.sock": rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1.RuntimeService
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3226369]: F0625 11:30:38.082979 3226369 daemon.go:57] Kubelet exited failed to run Kubelet: validate service connection: validate CRI v1 runtime API for endpoint "/var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd.sock": rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1.RuntimeService
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm systemd[1]: snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm systemd[1]: snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm systemd[1]: snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service: Consumed 4.173s CPU time.
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm systemd[1]: snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 11800.
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application microk8s.daemon-kubelite.
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm systemd[1]: snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service: Consumed 4.173s CPU time.
june 25 11:30:38 my-vm systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application microk8s.daemon-kubelite.

I have no clue what's causing this? Can anybody point me to a solution?
I found this: https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/4361
the behavior described in there looks similar, I'll try downgrading microk8s, but I'll appreciate any help.

I am encountering the same problem since we are trying to move from a gcloud VM to a libvirt VM.  It fails randomly.  Sometimes -rarely- we can install all our services, but most of the times the kubelite process dies and kubectl access fail and then nothing works for us.
